# No form data when while posting an array using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am currently using the following code to try and post an array using AJAX, however `console` shows no Form Data section when checking the Headers.

```
$(document).on("click", "#saveB", function () {
    var qry_array = [];
    var qry = query();
    var key = $('#save_key').val();
    qry_array[key]=qry;
    console.log(qry_array);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "favourites.php",
        data: {
            query: qry_array
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log (response);
        }
    });
});
```

> favourites.php

```
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
    ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );
    function saveQueries() {
        if (isset ( $_POST ['query'] )) {
            $arr = $_POST['query'];
            var_dump($arr);
        } else {
            echo "Key Missing";
        }
    }
    saveQueries ();
```

The response from `console` is `Key Missing` which means my `query` isn't being posted, why could this be??

Comment: Try this :  data: {
            'query': qry_array
        },

Comment: What does the `console.log(qry_array);` give you?

Comment: @The Guest: The quotes on a property name are only required if it contains special characters (`-` whitespace etc)

Comment: @CamilStaps `console.log(qry_array)` prints my array with the `key` value i.e `test:array`.

Comment: You have an extra `});` in your jQuery. Is it just a typing mistake over here?

Comment: @PrerakSola it is, corrected.

Comment: Did you try it without the function in your php file, like directly writing the required functionality without calling any function? I know it's lame, but still... ;)

Comment: Unless `key` is numerical it will not be serialized as array keys are numerical.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601982/why-is-my-ajax-post-function-not-working-with-button-click. You have got an answer for this

Comment: @ℛⱥℐℰşℎ That answer didn't fix my problem I had to use a different solution, I just accepted it because I didn't really have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $.post() instead:

```
$.post("favourites.php", { query: qry_array }).done(function(response) {
        console.log (response);
});
```

Comment: Tried this to no avail.